# How do I convert a unicode glyph into text

Tags: c#, .net

Given the following unicode character, how do I get the following string in C#:

expected result: `1f601`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although Daniels Answer is techincally correct, you will need to convert it to hex to get the result you have depicted

**Code**

```
var text = "";
var bytes = Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes(text);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("", bytes.Select(x => x.ToString("x"))));
```

**Output**

```
1f610
```

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ccrIuy)

---

**Additional Resources**

[String.Join Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Join_System_String_System_String___)

> Concatenates the elements of a specified array or the members of a
>   collection, using the specified separator between each element or
>   member.

[Enumerable.Select Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Projects each element of a sequence into a new form.

[Byte.ToString(String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.byte.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Byte_ToString_System_String_)

> Converts the value of the current Byte object to its equivalent string
>   representation using the specified format.

[Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings)

> "X" or "x" Hexadecimal Result: A hexadecimal string.
>
> - Supported by: Integral types only.
> - Precision specifier: Number of digits in the result string.
> - More information: The HexaDecimal ("X") Format Specifier.
>
>   - `255` ("X") -> `FF`
>   - `-1` ("x") -> `ff`
>   - `255` ("x4") -> `00ff`
>   - `-1` ("X4") -> `00FF`

Comment: Thanks, this is an extremely comprehensive answer.

Comment: For reference, here's how to do the exact opposite, UTF-32 code as `string` -> `char`. `var val = int.Parse("1F601", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
var c = char.ConvertFromUtf32(val);`

Answer (score 3):

You can encode it using UTF-32 encoding:

```
var text = "";
var bytes = Encoding.UTF32.getBytes(text);
```

Then you get an array of 4 bytes which represent those. Just get each group of 4 bytes and convert to hexa.